# Logs files becoming zero size after rotate

Tags: tomcat, logging

I'm trying to run a logrotate for access, hostmanager and manager logs in tomcat. I have written following script which been **emptying files** after rotation. Apart from that the deletion and compression in postrotate and preroate was working fine.

```
/srv/www/tomcat/Container*/logs/access*
/srv/www/tomcat/Container*/logs/catalina.*.log
/srv/www/tomcat/Container*/logs/host-manager.*.log
/srv/www/tomcat/Container*/logs/localhost.*.log
/srv/www/tomcat/Container*/logs/manager.*.log

{
    missingok
    notifempty
    daily
    rotate 0
    prerotate
        /bin/find /srv/www/tomcat/Container*/logs/  -maxdepth 1 -mtime +2 -name "*.log" -exec gzip {} \; || true
        endscript
    postrotate
      /bin/find /srv/www/tomcat/Container*/logs/  -mindepth 1 -mtime +10 -name "*.gz" -delete || true


  endscript
}
```

Comment: Where is the emptying command?

Comment: I mean, the files are of some MB size and while after rotate the files were zipping and becoming empty 0 size, all the log file content was clearing out. Which it should not be for me.

Example: 
access.2016-05-19.log   --> Which was 101Mb before rotate
access.2016-05-19.log.gz --> 0Mb after rotate

Answer (score 0):

The following should work, compress every rotated file and use maxage instead of your find command:

```
{
    missingok
    notifempty
    daily
    compress
    maxage 12
}
```

If you want to compress after two days:

```
{
    missingok
    notifempty
    daily
    maxage 12
    postrotate
        /bin/find /srv/www/tomcat/Container*/logs/ -maxdepth 1 -mtime +2 -name "*.log.?" -exec gzip {} \;
    endscript
}
```